# How do I change the font color of specific variables in corrplot in R?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

How do I change the color of the font `tl.col` specific for certain variables like in the image?

Do I have to create a variable before? Or can you select columns within the command?

```
corrplot(cor(iris[,-5]), tl.col="black", tl.cex=0.8, tl.srt=70)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tl.col` takes a vector with colors for each variable. So you can set the color for each variable directly with the `tl.col` argument like this:

```
corrplot(cor(iris[,-5]), tl.col=c("red", "red", "blue", "blue"), tl.cex=0.8, tl.srt=70)
```

Alternatively you can define the colors within a function:

```
colors <- ifelse(grepl("Sepal", names(iris)[-5]), "red", "blue")
corrplot(cor(iris[,-5]), tl.col=colors, tl.cex=0.8, tl.srt=70)

# or 

corrplot(cor(iris[,-5]), tl.col=ifelse(grepl("Sepal", names(iris)[-5]), "red", "blue"),
tl.cex=0.8, tl.srt=70)
```

Comment: Thanks @tamtam Would it be an alternative where instead of grep by name, I grep by column number? (ie: columns 1:2 red, columns 3:4 blue. In my real data I am working with multiple variables with different names

Comment: There might be different solutions. But if you need to define just a few colors you may try this: `colors <-  rep(NA, 4)
colors[1:2] <- "red"
colors[3:4] <- "blue"` Create a vector with the length of your columns and rename the  elements with a color.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
library (corrplot)
library(MASS)
library(calibrate)
data("iris")

corrplot(cor(iris[,-5]), cl.pos = "n", tl.pos = "n")  
textxy(0,1,labs=c("Petal.Width"),cex=0.8,offset=-0.2,col="blue")
textxy(0,2,labs=c("Petal.Length"),cex=0.8,offset=-0.2,col="blue")
textxy(4,5,labs=c("Petal.Width"),cex=0.8,offset=0,col="blue",srt=45)
textxy(3,5,labs=c("Petal.Length"),cex=0.8,offset=0,col="blue",srt=45)

textxy(0,3,labs=c("Sepal.Width"),cex=0.8,offset=-0.2,col="red")
textxy(0,4,labs=c("Sepal.Length"),cex=0.8,offset=-0.2,col="red")
textxy(2,5,labs=c("Sepal.Width"),cex=0.8,offset=0,col="red",srt=45)
textxy(1,5,labs=c("Sepal.Length"),cex=0.8,offset=0,col="red",srt=45)
```

Basically you have to remove the variable names displayed by corrplot and textxy creates labels. You have to set position, color..., it's a shortcut for your problem

Comment: If you don't want to erase the legend bar just ignore cl.pos= "n" which is the line removing it